# AWS beanstalk - Python application fails when updating env variables

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using AWS elastic beanstalk to serve a custom python app. Everything works fine except updating environment variables.

If I try changing through `eb setenv FOO=bar`  (or changing in the console) the application stops recognizing the **all** the env variables. Restarting the server or sending a new deploy solves the problem, but the client could experience a downtime or a 400/500 error.

I'm almost sure that I need to use a configdeploy hook but don't know how.

Thanks!

---

Configs:

Python 3.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.3

**0_python.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: 'configs/wsgi.py'
    NumProcesses: 6
    NumThreads: 15
container_commands:
  01_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
  02_traceenable:
    command: 'echo "TraceEnable Off" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

**1_apache.config**

```
container_commands:
  01_setup_apache:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_deflate.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_deflate.conf"
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content:    |
      RewriteEngine On
        <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
          RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
        </If>
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi_custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your env vars in `.config` files with

`option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    FOO: bar`

Comment: I tried that a few days ago and the error was exactly the same. But i tried again today and worked!
Thanks for suggesting me to try again!